# Link não clicavel

Tags: html, link

Estou criando um site e estou com um problema, eu tenho uma `tag` de link mas não consigo clicar nela. Se eu colocar ela em qualquer outro lugar do código funciona, mas nessa especifica não. 
(o link que estou citando é esse do "Saiba mais")

```
<section class="ftco-section-2">
          <div class="container d-flex" id="franquia">
            <div class="section-2-blocks-wrapper row">
              <div class="img col-sm-12 col-lg-6" style="background-image: url('images/img/Bike4.png');">
              </div>
              <div class="text col-lg-6 ftco-animate">
                <div class="text-inner align-self-start">
                  <h3 class="heading">Seja nosso Franqueado.</h3>
                  <p>(Texto)</p>

                  <p>(Texto)</p>
                  <a href="?pg=franquia">Saiba mais.</a>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
</section>
```

Comment: tente ser mais objetivo e claro nas suas perguntas. Evite dados que não vão de acordo ao escopo/regras do site como no seu titulo "provavelmente culpa do programador cego"

Answer (score 2):

Seu código aparentemente não apresenta nenhum problema com a [função](https://sites.google.com/site/sitesrecord/o-que-e-um-link) do link.

```html
<section class="ftco-section-2">
          <div class="container d-flex" id="franquia">
            <div class="section-2-blocks-wrapper row">
              <div class="img col-sm-12 col-lg-6" style="background-image: url('images/img/Bike4.png');">
              </div>
              <div class="text col-lg-6 ftco-animate">
                <div class="text-inner align-self-start">
                  <h3 class="heading">Seja nosso Franqueado.</h3>
                  <p>(Texto)</p>

                  <p>(Texto)</p>
                  <a href="?pg=franquia">Saiba mais.</a>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
</section>
```

Você checou se o endereço de redirecionamento está correto?

Aqui umas páginas caso esteja com dificuldade de manusear os mesmos:

- [Entendendo a síntaxe de links com HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)
- [Links - âncora e alguns atributos](http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/htm/htm-lin2.htm)

Comment: Pelo q eu vi a div esta se sobrepondo ao link, pq quando eu uso em outras partes do código funciona normalmente.

Comment: @Onaicul vc viu seu código que coloquei no executavel acima? qnd vc coloca o cursor do mouse no Saiba Mais ele está chamando o link

Comment: Sim. provavelmente é alguma coisa no css do template q estou usando, pq executando por aqui funciona, mas se usar no site continua com o msm problema. Mas vlw ai pela ajuda, vou continuar tentando ;3